# How to install plugins to /usr for a snap?

Tags: snap, plugins

### Goal

I would like to install the [OBS Color Monitor plugin](https://github.com/norihiro/obs-color-monitor) to the snap version of OBS Studio.

### Problem

The [plugin installs](https://github.com/norihiro/obs-color-monitor/issues/52) to the `/usr/share` and `/usr/lib` directories which are not accessible for the snap so the plugin provided sources are not available inside OBS. It works fine with the regular apt-get version, but unfortunately that version of OBS has major bugs while the snap version doesn't.

### What I tried

I tried installing with the `--classic` flag, but it gives this error:

> Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap obs-studio

### Question

How to install a plugin that uses system directories? Is there a snap version of the file system I can access, or a way to configure the snap to also load extra files to its own file system? Are confined snaps just not extensible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't **edit** those read-only directories, you **override** them with a local directory.

Create a local plug-in directory. The correct name and path of the directory is important:

`mkdir -p ~/snap/obs-studio/current/.config/obs-studio/plugins/`

Put your plug-ins there.

Snapd will automatically use the override directories when detected.

Source: https://github.com/snapcrafters/obs-studio/issues/46

Comment: How should this work? The plugin is installed from a `.deb` file via `dpkg`. It installs into `/usr`, not into OBS's own directories. Also, if the file system is read-only why can't the snap version read this stuff inside `/usr`?

Comment: Sigh. Don't mix deb and snap. That's just asking for hours of needless tail-chasing pain. Extract the plugin file(s) from the deb, or get the file(s) from upstream. Put the plugin file(s) in the place described in this answer.